# I get a query error 'unknown column' while the column exists

Tags: mysql

I get error **(1054): Unknown column 'wp_jpnx_survey_code.supplier_id' in 'field list'**
But that column does exist... Does anyone know why or how to fix this?

This is the code I used:

```sql
CREATE VIEW survey_codes_complete_overview AS SELECT *,
wp_jpnx_survey_code.supplier_id AS a_id,
wp_jpnx_survey_supplier_info.supplier_id AS b_id FROM
wp_jpnx_survey_code AS a LEFT JOIN wp_jpnx_survey_supplier_info AS b
ON a.supplier_id = b.supplier_id;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using aliases for those tables. So, specify the alias when selecting the column.

```
CREATE VIEW survey_codes_complete_overview AS 
SELECT *, 
a.supplier_id AS a_id, 
b.supplier_id AS b_id 
FROM wp_jpnx_survey_code AS a 
LEFT JOIN wp_jpnx_survey_supplier_info AS b 
ON a.supplier_id = b.supplier_id
```